# Flipped NSView mouse coordinates

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a subclass of NSView that re-implements a number of the mouse event functions. For instance in mouseDown to get the point from the NSEvent I use:

```
NSEvent *theEvent; // <- argument to function

NSPoint p = [theEvent locationInWindow];
p = [self convertPoint:p fromView:nil];
```

However the coordinates seem to be flipped, (0, 0) is in the bottom left of the window?

EDIT: I have already overridden the isFlipped method to return TRUE, but it has only affected drawing. Sorry, can't believe I forgot to put that straight away.

Answer (score 7):

What do you mean by flipped? Mac uses a LLO (lower-left-origin) coordinate system for everything.

**EDIT** I can't reproduce this with a simple project. I created a single `NSView` implemented like this:

```
@implementation FlipView
- (BOOL)isFlipped {
  return YES;
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  NSPoint p = [theEvent locationInWindow];
  p = [self convertPoint:p fromView:nil];
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromPoint(p));
}
@end
```

I received the coordinates I would expect. Removing the `isFlipped` switched the orientation as expected. Do you have a simple project that demonstrates your problmem?

Comment: I meant, I had already overridden the isFlipped method. My fault, I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: In my testing, `isFlipped { YES } ` *will* convert the point to a top-left origin if you use convertPoint: **fromView:**. But *not* if you use convertPoint: **toView:** – this is expected, since `toView:` assumes that the point is already in the `self` view’s coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

I found this so obnoxious - until one day I just sat down and refused to get up until I had something that worked perfectly .  Here it is..  called via...

```
-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)click{
  NSPoint mD = [NSScreen wtfIsTheMouse:click
                        relativeToView:self];
}
```

invokes a Category on NSScreen....

```
@implementation NSScreen (FlippingOut)
+ (NSPoint)wtfIsTheMouse:(NSEvent*)anyEevent 
          relativeToView:(NSView *)view {
   NSScreen *now = [NSScreen currentScreenForMouseLocation];
    return [now flipPoint:[now convertToScreenFromLocalPoint:event.locationInWindow relativeToView:view]];
}
- (NSPoint)flipPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint {
         return (NSPoint) { aPoint.x, 
   self.frame.size.height - aPoint.y  };
}
- (NSPoint)convertToScreenFromLocalPoint:(NSPoint)point 
      relativeToView:(NSView *)view {
    NSPoint winP, scrnP, flipScrnP; 
    if(self) {
       winP = [view convertPoint:point toView:nil];
       scrnP = [[view window] convertBaseToScreen:winP];
       flipScrnP = [self flipPoint:scrnP];
       flipScrnP.y += [self frame].origin.y;
       return flipScrnP;
       }    return NSZeroPoint;
}
@end
```

Hope this can prevent just one minor *freakout*.. *somewhere, someday*.  For the children, damnit. I beg of you.. for the children.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
NSPoint location =  [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
location.y = self.frame.size.height - location.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't "flipped", necessarily, that's just how Quartz does coordinates. [An excerpt from the documentation on Quartz 2D:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html)

> A point in user space is represented by a coordinate pair (x,y), where x represents the location along the horizontal axis (left and right) and y represents the vertical axis (up and down). The origin of the user coordinate space is the point (0,0). The origin is located at the lower-left corner of the page, as shown in Figure 1-4. In the default coordinate system for Quartz, the x-axis increases as it moves from the left toward the right of the page. The y-axis increases in value as it moves from the bottom toward the top of the page.

I'm not sure what your question is, though. Are you looking for a way to get the "flipped" coordinates? If so, you can subclass your NSView, overriding the `-(BOOL)isFlipped` method to return YES.